# Heist preparation always fail

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm now preparing for one of the heists. Right now I gotta get 4 *Gauntlets* and mod them. The problem is:

- I'm playing as Trevor and I only have $11127.
- I got into a *Gauntlet* and the mission started.
- I should drive it into the *Los Santos Customs*:

  - If I hit anything the mission fails with words: *"The required mods cannot purchased due to insufficient funds"*.
  - I did my best to get to *Los Santos Customs* without a scratch and I made it.
- However, after preparing the vehicle for a heist($11000) the mission failed again! And again with the same description

What should I do? I failed this mission on purpose more than 10 times in a row to skip it, but this option doesn't appear.

And I can't switch characters because only Trevor is used in this "mission"

Comment: get more funds first...

Comment: I played that mission as Michael.  You probably can't switch once you've started, but you should be able to be who you want before you start.  The only other answer is, as @ratchetfreak said, get more funds!  I honestly don't know how you've got so little money at that point in the game.

Comment: You can drop a mission by exiting the game session. This will allow you to switch characters. It might be easier to just get additional funds.  If the heist applys to all 3 playable characters it doesn't matter who steals the Gauntlet(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also experiencing this problem. What I found is that you have to have enough money in hand to pay for all three cars, so $33000 plus damage repair.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this. I had $15k with Michael and did one car. I then had the money come in from my properties which gave me about $13k but then it failed when I paid $11k to fix the next car. I switched to Franklyn who had $16k and that failed as well.

Having done a bit of [research](http://gta.wikia.com/Glitches), it seems that it's a bug in the game. I re-started my Xbox and that fixed the problem.